# Kafka offset management and sync with DB

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, kafka-consumer-api, system-design

I'm working on an application using Kafka stream and a database.

In my application, I am managing Kafka offset manually and committing the offset in case of successful message processing only (i.e after processing and updating to DB is successful).

However, if after updating the DB my application goes down before committing, then when it comes back up it results in a duplicate write to DB because of uncommitted offset.

I want to avoid these duplicates, while still making sure that I'm processing every single message. What is the right approach to do this?

EDIT: My update to DB basically increments a counter for a record by some value. So MERGE statements are not an option.

Comment: For RDBMS use MERGE statement. For nosql databases like Cassandra, duplicate row with same primary key will simply overwrite without any error.

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu Thanks for your answer. Have updated my question to show why these are not viable options for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.

Kafka supports exactly-once semantics. But when you're writing data to an external data store, you need to ensure the exactly-once on the consumer side.

One way to achieve that (as proposed by Jay Kreps [here](https://medium.com/@jaykreps/exactly-once-support-in-apache-kafka-55e1fdd0a35f)) is, maintain the Kafka offset in the data store as part of a single transaction. Therefore, if you maintain the last offset for each partition, you can always ignore the messages from a given partition when you recieve an offset less than the one stored in the DB.

However, there is a caveat in this approach. If you have a multi datacenter active-active deployment where the consumers fallback to a different different data center cluster if the primary cluster goes down, you cannot blindly rely on the offset. Offset is a physical id and the offset of a message in one cluster can be different from the offset of the replicated message on the other cluster.

In these circumstances, I think the right approach will be to leverage Kafka streams and maintain the counts in a Kafka table (`KTable`) stored in a compacted Kafka topic. Kafka internally will use the producer id, epoch, transaction id etc. to ensure the exactly once semantics.